# Angular 5 generate Html to pdf?

Tags: html, typescript, pdf, angular5

I've 2 questions my project is in ANGULAR 5.

Am looking for a way to generate HTML to PDF.
Generated pdf shouldn’t be an image. It should be like the Actual PDF user can copy text etc.

Note: please don't suggest `jsPdf`.

Another approach is am looking for a way to send the whole HTML with inserted values to an Endpoint.
The Html I am trying to send is Only content editable divs.

How can I do this?

Help and suggestion would be appreciated.
THanks

Comment: Hi @The Mechanic, did you find a way to do it ?

Comment: @Linpter I did a trick for that. First I converted data into base64 data and after that  opened in new tab by adding some hardcoded text.

Answer (score 1):

You have also this:

https://github.com/moshensky/html-to-pdf-converter

But in my opinion the best way is to send just the data you want to format to a backend service and format it in the backend.